# ASP.NET Core Preview Browsed Image

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209241/preview-an-image-in-razor-view), but it uses a JavaScript. I am trying to apply this script but in razor codes but I don't know how to do it, I searched/googled with different keyword but all answers don't use a razor code. Can anyone help me ?

Here is a part of the cshtml page.

```
    <tr>
        <td><label>Image</label></td>
        <td>
            <script>
                function ImgPre(input) {
                    if (input.files[0]) {
                        var uploadImg = new FileReader();
                        uploadImg.onload = function (displayImg) {
                            $("#imagePreviewer").attr('src', displayImg.target.result);
                        }
                        uploadImg.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                    }
                }
            </script>

            <input type="file" accept="image/*" asp-for="Image" onchange="ImgPre(this)" />

            @{
                
                string base64 = "";
                if (Model.Image != null)
                {
                    base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image);
                }
                var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64);
            }
            <img id="imagePreviewer" src="@imgSrc" width="150" />

        </td>
    </tr>
```

how can I write the code in the `<script></script>` tag to be similar to the one with `@{ }`

I have been struggling to find a solution but I can't find any. Can someone help me, please ?

Comment: Here's a [explanation answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727972/what-is-section-scripts-and-what-it-is-used-for)  for @section Scripts. If you only want the js code to take effect in this page, you can remove `@section Scripts` but continue to have `<script>`, and you also need to add jquery separately in this page

Comment: Why are you rendering images as Base64-encoded strings? That approach won't scale for images larger than a few kilobytes. Why can't you serve a reference to an image resource served separately?

Comment: @Dai This is just a thumbnail image for the product and will be resized to 150px, also, I am somehow new to MVC and JS so I thought if I could use c# in razor I could utilize what I know

Answer (score 0):

You can write javascript in your cshtml file by surrounding the  with `@section Scripts{}`.

It should looks like

```
<input type="file" id=" ImgUpload" onchange="ImgPre(this)" />
<button id="butImg">Upload</button>
<p>
  <img id="ImgPreview" />
</p>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function ImgPre(input) {
          if (input.files[0]) {
            var uploadimg = new FileReader();
            uploadimg.onload = function(displayimg) {
              $("#ImgPreview").attr('src', displayimg.target.result);
            }
            uploadimg.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
          }
        }
    </script>
}
```